# Getting client IP passing through AWS API gateway to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API gateway to call my APIs from mobile devices.i Use http integration and connect it to my EC2 server.
i want to get the Client IP in ec2 .
I already found a solution to get client ip using lamda function [enter link description here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=648053)

But i need to get client ip in my EC2 Backend.
Please suggest any possible solution

Comment: Have you tried capturing the value of [`$context.identity.sourceIp`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) in the integration request?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for your response, i got that solution. but it is accessible from lambda function right?
i need to get ip in my EC2 instance where the request is passing through htpp integration

Comment: This `$context` object is a variable in API Gateway, usable without an associated Lambda function.  But also, your incoming request at EC2 should have an `X-Forwarded-For` header showing the chain of IP addresses that handled the request.  Do you see this?